# Obtaining stars vector position in relation to the center of the galaxy at a given date

Tags: star, galaxy, coordinate, positional-astronomy

How can someone obtain such vector, for stars in the Milky Way?

Input should be star data (from a catalog, eg: Hipparcos) and Julian Date.

Output should be a Vector Position (in pc) in relation to the galactic center.

Comment: A vector position requires a reference axis set as well as a central point.  What do you propose to use as to define the reference with.

Comment: Presumably the galactic coordinate system (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_coordinate_system)

Comment: As stated, the axis center should be set on the Galactic Center (center of the Milky Way). Galactic Coordinates alone aren't enough to answer this question. I need to know how to transform the input data (star data and date) into the required position vector.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is helpful or not, but [this paper (pdf)](http://www.rssd.esa.int/SA-general/Projects/Hipparcos/CATALOGUE_VOL1/sect1_05.pdf) details how to transform between different coordinate systems.

Comment: It could be possible, but from the data available on sites like [Sinbad](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/) it appears that distant stars have more data to the used on the calculation, than a simple horizontal coordinate system (where you would include the required date) to galactic coordinate system transformation.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: It turns out a major problem with galaxy-center-based coordinates is that we don't actually know how far from us the center of the galaxy actually is. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_Center estimates vary between 24,800 and 28,400 light years. You could arbitrarily choose a value, but the results would be off by at least 2,000 light years in some cases.

I was surprised that I couldn't find something like this 
online directly. The closest I found is the file 
"heasarc_tycho2.tdat.gz" on 
http://heasarc.nasa.gov/FTP/heasarc/dbase/dump/

The format is explained on 
http://heasarc.nasa.gov/W3Browse/all/tycho2.html and it 
includes the galactic latitude and longitude which are 
explained here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_coordinate_system

Using this information, you'd still have to compute the 
positions yourself, but at least all of the data is there.

Of course, as others have noted, you can take any star 
catalog with any set of coordinates and convert it to the 
format you need. The catalog I list above just makes it a 
little easier, since they're precomputed some of the steps 
for you.

As you mention above, SIMBAD also includes galactic 
coordinates, but I couldn't find an easy way to download 
the entire catalog.

Comment: Just read your edit. Our goal is just to estimate star movements around the galaxy and plot them in 3D for scientific disclosure. Very precise scientific accuracy would be a plus, but it is not really required.

Comment: For that, wouldn't you just need the proper motion of stars?

Comment: I dont really know. This issue began when I was asked to create a 3D plot of the two star 'orbits' mentioned in [this article](http://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/pdf/2013/11/aa21012-12.pdf). In the article they dont use proper motion.